# Get related posts excluding current post in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, categories, relatedto

In Craft 3, I’m trying to get the five most recent other posts sharing a category with the current post.  I got this far:

```
{% for relatedPost in craft.entries.relatedTo(entry.newsCategory).limit(5) %}
```

That gets five posts sharing the current post’s category, *including* the current post if it happens to be recently posted.  How do I exclude the current post from the returned results, without just dropping it from the five so I’m only left with four?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To exclude the current post use the current post's id with a *"not"* clause in the `id` query param.

```
{% for relatedPost in craft.entries.relatedTo(entry.newsCategory).id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(5).all() %}
```

Comment: Beauty!  Thank you!  If you don’t mind another question, where do you recommend people go to learn this sort of thing?

Comment: Craft Stack Exchange is the usual place or asking on the Craft Slack channel. https://craftcms.com/community  The Craft community is very helpful.